# Resize elementary OS partition to full disk partition

Tags: system-installation, release-juno, disk-management

I've installed elementary OS 5.0 to a /dev/sda3 partition alongside two NTFS /dev/sda1 and /dev/sda2 partitions, whose mount point is set before.

Now, I'd want to delete the first two NTFS partitions and extend the elementary OS partition to the whole disk (not encrypted) through a live USB disk and GParted, and make it bootable.

How can I do that without loss of data?

Thank you.

Comment: Please do not forget to mark answers if you they are helpful. If posted answers are not clear please do not forget ask for clarification, though the [community](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/users) always try to post a clear answer.

Answer (score 1):

To resize elementary OS partition please boot into a live-usb of elementary OS and select the *try* option. Then please open GParted and resize your elementary OS partition. You can just resize it, no need to delete or remove any partition, system will automatically do what it needs to do. No loss of data.